# naviagtionBar height and statusBar height size

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

In the use of the iphone 5, the `navigationBar` and `statusBar` normal height, but under the iphone6 or iphone6plus navigationBar and the statusBar height is bigger, not 64, the likelihood is scaling.

The problem is that I want iphone6 or iphone6plus to also become a normal 64, but they don't know how to find this code in the project.

Comment: you use Default naviagtionBar or custom naviagtionBar? because Default  naviagtionBar size is 64. @lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like bigger, but they still 64, Apple would do math to convert visual effect by itself. You can try to log it

`Target->iPhone 6`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"navigation bar height:%f, status bar height:%f", self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
}
```

The log

`2015-07-25 13:14:40.252 Test001[62901:7144906] navigation bar height:44.000000, status bar height:20.000000`

Comment: Because the code is not I, I don't know what method view navigation bar and status bar gets bigger, as you say they were a total of 64 indeed, if you guess what he used the methods lead to this.

Comment: put your code here. how did you find the height is not 64?